# speakers dont work in macbook pro

Tags: macbook, speakers

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Macbook Pro - Sound doesn’t work and there’s a red light coming out of my headphone jack.](https://superuser.com/questions/37777/macbook-pro-sound-doesnt-work-and-theres-a-red-light-coming-out-of-my-headpho)

I have a macbook pro but my Built-in stereo speakers don't work and it comes a red light from Headphone out/optical digital audio out port. my Built-in stereo speakers aren't dead because at first that OS runs it comes a sound from them but as soon as the macbook pro is ready when i play music they don't work and In the SOUND in system preferences the name of device for sound output is Digital Out. Is the problem from hardware or software. Is there any solution?

Comment: Dupe: http://superuser.com/questions/37777/macbook-pro-sound-doesnt-work-and-theres-a-red-light-coming-out-of-my-headpho

Comment: ... and by the way, using a toothpick worked great for me!

Answer (score 0):

You are using bootcamp, correct?  That's just apple neutering their products when you try to use them for any purpose other than what they have prescribed.

You might want to try uninstalling bootcamp managers from within the windows partition and then installing the drivers that windows recommends, but be careful: I don't know if that might potentially mess up your mac partition.